# Should I use ImageView or TextField?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode9

I'm trying to write my first real app in Xcode 9. I have the TableViews set up the issue is the final ViewController I want to put several sentences. Almost a paragraph that is non-editable. I can either take picture from the source or type out all the sentences but how do I do that in TextField? ImageView would be easier to do but I need it to go to a specific image that is not in the Photo Library or something you take with the Camera. Thank you.

Comment: Did you looked at `UILabel`?

Comment: You can either use a `UILabel` or a `UITextView`, on `UITextView` just set the property `isEditable` to `false` and `isScrollEnabled` to `false`. and on `UILabel` set `numberOfLines` to `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a UILabel with Lines property equal to 0. This will allow you to have any number of lines suitable for several sentences or a paragraph. If you want to put line breaks, just use alt + enter when typing the contents.

[image]

Comment: I'm new to coding so what I did learn didn't go into too much detail as far as formatting. I want to set it up almost as if I would could change the format like in a document with indentations, bullet points, etc.